# Adding UI Bar Button Items for WebView but app crashing

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've added the following code to my iOS project in XCode. It allows me to add multiple buttons to my UINavigation Controller - the items show fine in the app but when I press the 'Refresh' or 'Back' button the app crashes

What I'm trying to do is create 3 buttons - Refresh, GoBack and GoForward.

The error Im getting says Undeclared selector 'refresh'

```
// Create the refresh, fixed-space (optional), and profile buttons.
UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];




//    // Optional: if you want to add space between the refresh & profile buttons
//    UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpaceBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
//    fixedSpaceBarButtonItem.width = 12;

UIBarButtonItem *profileBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToProfile)];
profileBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[profileBarButtonItem, /* fixedSpaceBarButtonItem, */ refreshBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: is there a refresh: method in your viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [Link](http://osmorphis.blogspot.in/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html)

Will be add more buttons in navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Check the declaration/definition of your `refresh` method.

As per your code  `action:@selector(refresh:);` the `refresh` method should have atleast one argument.

If your definition of `refresh` method has not arguments then it should be like `action:@selector(refresh);`